# PiHole running in docker cannot reply IPv6 connections from ULA address

Tags: networking, docker, ipv6, internet, pi-hole

After reading few guides on how to setup PiHole with docker and IPv6 I tried to do it in my network. First things first, my ISP provides me with a Prefix Delegation which is then used to provide addresses to the rest of the network though router assignment (RA). The prefix is not static and is rotated every few days.

### ULA setup

I am using a Ubiquity UDM-Pro and I have added the ULA prefix to the `br0` interface as follows,

```bash
ip address add fd79:71d8:a0b7::1/64 dev br0
```

After which, all of my IPv6 capable devices are immediately assigned with a ULA address with that prefix.

### docker configuration

To get docker working, I had to explicitly enable IPv6 and provide the cidr range. To do so, I created the `daemon.json` in `/etc/docker` with the following contents,

```json
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd79:71d8:a0b7::/80"
}
```

Then I added to the NAT table in `ip6tables` the following command,

```bash
sudo ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s fd79:71d8:a0b7::/80 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Which allows the `docker0` interface to receive IPv6 traffic. Of course, since these changes do not persist across reboots I also installed `iptables-persistent` and `netfilter-persistent` packages which allows these changes to persist across reboots.

I checked that IPv6 connectivity could be established by using,

```bash
$ docker run --rm -t busybox ping6 -c 4 google.com
PING google.com (2a00:1450:4017:811::200e): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:4017:811::200e: seq=0 ttl=56 time=62.514 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:4017:811::200e: seq=1 ttl=56 time=61.256 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:4017:811::200e: seq=2 ttl=56 time=61.503 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:4017:811::200e: seq=3 ttl=56 time=61.850 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 61.256/61.780/62.514 ms
```

### pihole configuration

The configuration of `pihole` was fairly straightforward, I used the following `yaml` saved as `pihole.yaml` for the `docker-compose`,

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      # dns ports
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      # ports for http interface
      - "19080:80/tcp"
      - "19443:443/tcp"
    environment:
      # redacted full address
      FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4: 10.10.x.25
      # redacted full address
      FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV6: fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38
    # IPs of your DNS entries
    dns:
      # this is for resolved conf, assuming you have ubuntu and disabled it
      - 127.0.0.1
      # proper DNS entries follow
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
      - 2606:4700:4700::1111
      - 2606:4700:4700::1001
    # Recommended but not required (DHCP needs NET_ADMIN)
    #   https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Which I brought up using `docker-compose -f pihole.yaml up`.

## Issue: replies come from another address or timeout

The issue is that I am not able to use this from other computers. In the machine the `docker` image is running I am able to use `dig` without any issue. For example, I get the following if I type the command in the host machine,

```bash
$ dig @fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38 -p 53 google.com AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> @fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38 -p 53 google.com AAAA
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60684
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     83  IN  AAAA    2a00:1450:4017:805::200e

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38#53(fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon May 15 01:44:42 EEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

However, then I type this in another Linux based machine - the command just times out, namely,

```bash
dig -6 @fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38 -p 53 google.com
;; communications error to fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38#53: timed out
;; communications error to fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38#53: timed out
;; communications error to fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38#53: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> -6 @fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38 -p 53 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached
```

To investigate, I tried to see if the address was block or anything like that, but `netcat` shows that the port is open for business,

```bash
nc -z fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38 53 -v

Connection to fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
```

Upon further investigation, it seems that using `dig` from MacOS it gives a bit more information. The connection does not seem to timeout per se but reply from **another** address.

The output of `dig` in MacOS is as follows using the same address as before,

```bash
$ dig -6 @fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38 google.com
;; reply from unexpected source: fd79:71d8:a0b7::60b#53, expected fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38#53
;; reply from unexpected source: fd79:71d8:a0b7::60b#53, expected fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38#53
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> -6 @fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:5043:6018:fb4f:ae38 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Using the address that is being said to provide the answers works as expected,

```bash
dig -6 @fd79:71d8:a0b7::60b google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> -6 @fd79:71d8:a0b7::60b google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9440
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     156 IN  A   172.217.17.142
;; Query time: 22 msec
;; SERVER: fd79:71d8:a0b7::60b#53(fd79:71d8:a0b7::60b)
;; WHEN: Mon May 15 01:51:58 EEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 55
```

Looking at the interface IPs using `ip -6 addr show dev enp9s0f1` reveals the following,

```bash
5: enp9s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:xx:xx:xx:xx:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.x.25/24 brd 10.10.x.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp9s0f1
       valid_lft 83538sec preferred_lft 83538sec
    inet6 2a02:587:<redacted>/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 83539sec preferred_lft 83539sec
    inet6 fd79:71d8:a0b7::60b/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 83539sec preferred_lft 83539sec
    inet6 2a02:587:<redacted>/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 73590sec preferred_lft 73590sec
    inet6 fd79:71d8:a0b7:0:...:ae38/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86138sec preferred_lft 86138sec
    inet6 fe80::1ea:<redacted>:eb62/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Why does the reply come from another address? I have disabled RFC4941 which uses a different address for outbound addresses, as is evidenced from here,

```bash
$ nmcli con show "Wired connection 4" | grep ipv6.ip
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       0 (disabled)
```

The routing for IPv6 is as follows,

```bash
$ ip -6 route show
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a02:587:...::60b dev enp9s0f1 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
2a02:587:...::/64 dev enp9s0f1 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fd79:71d8:a0b7::60b dev enp9s0f1 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fd79:71d8:a0b7::/80 dev docker0 proto kernel metric 256 linkdown pref medium
fd79:71d8:a0b7::/80 dev docker0 metric 1024 linkdown pref medium
fd79:71d8:a0b7::/64 dev enp9s0f1 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev docker0 proto kernel metric 256 linkdown pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br-5c9052b3a88b proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br-ba2b20fe7aa1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth3fb9416 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth7a050e3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vethe299802 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth5110238 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev cali7ffb27b031d proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev calib5cff4a4a14 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev cali6b881403436 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev calib1a2ba7ef9f proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev cali20c73fad203 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev calib05d5a88d5c proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vxlan.calico proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp9s0f1 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::...:62b3 dev enp9s0f1 proto ra metric 100 pref high
```

Can anyone help me understand why is this happening? I just cannot figure out why the response is coming from another address all the time... I would like to use stable ULA addresses for my DNS server because I cannot use the prefix provided by my ISP since it changes over time nor the privacy addresses as again these change over time.